# When does working for a salary stop making sense?

Tags: early-retirement

Assume you increase “x” of your net worth each year given a job you don’t particularly like/dislike much. When and at which salary/nw would you say you’d better be doing something else (family/hobbies/etc) or a part time and more enjoyable job instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you value what your leisure time is worth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115254/how-do-you-value-what-your-leisure-time-is-worth)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 25 times annual expenses rule and leaving no estate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46575/the-25-times-annual-expenses-rule-and-leaving-no-estate)

Comment: Generally, this is also related to [Opportunity Cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost). The tradeoff being a job that pays $X, or something else you can do that's (to you) equivalent of $X to you in some way.  This is a very personal question. I know some people who would be happy making say $30k a year doing a boring job that has excellent work/life balance and others yet who won't stop until they're way into the six figures. What would make you happy is a question I don't think anyone here can answer.

Comment: This feels like a better question for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems like an opinion-based question, and honestly not fit for Stack Exchange in general.

Answer (score 10):

It all depends on if "you" (specifically, the people in your house) are living below your means.

IOW, if the debt is piling up, then obviously not.  But if you can still (relatively) comfortably (to clarify: that includes paying for your hobbies and other leisure activities) survive on the income generated by a lower-paying job, then by all means find a job that makes you happy.

Note that this all hinges on you controlling your finances (know where all your money goes, and follow a budget), not letting your finances control you.

Comment: It's important to remember too that hobbies and leisure activities cost money as well. You have to figure in the expected increased spending on other activities as well as the decreased income.

Comment: @Ian that's included in "*comfortably* survive".  I'll make that more clear.

Answer (score 3):

> When and at which salary/Net worth would you say you’d better be doing
> something else (family/hobbies/etc) or a part time and more enjoyable
> job instead?

To be able to do this you need to know that your new salary will support your lifestyle. By new salary that means money from a new full-time job, new part-time job, or hobby. It can mean money from your retirement sources of income if you are are old enough.

But when figuring your current lifestyle costs don't forget the money you need to save/invest to fund your retirement years. Breaking even when you are working age but not saving for retirement will force you to work longer, or to require you to work forever.

Answer (score 1):

When to retire involves crunching the numbers to see if your assets and retirement income will cover your living costs no matter how long you live and no matter what the economy does.

The difficult part of this is estimating your future expenses and adhering to a disciplined spending plan once you retire.

There are lots of online retirement calculators as well as
professional retirement planners.